# Lightning:select isnt working

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Picklist values are coming properly when I use ui:namespace, but If i change ui to lightning name space, picklist values aren't coming properly

```
    <aura:component>
       <!--<ui:inputselect aura:id="BudgetNET"  label="Budget" /> --> <!-- its working -->
     <!-- If I change ui:input selet to Lightning select its not working  -->
    <lightning:select label="" aura:id="BudgetNET" class="slds-select" />
  </aura:component>
```

javascript code

```
 ({
doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
 var budgetval=component.find("BudgetNET").get("v.value");
}
});
```

Helper:

```
fetchPickListVal: function(component, fieldName, elementId) {
    var action = component.get("c.getselectOptions");
    action.setParams({
        "objObject": component.get("v.objInfo"),
        "fld": fieldName
    });
    var opts = [];
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        if (response.getState() == "SUCCESS") {
            var allValues = response.getReturnValue();
            // alert(allValues);
           if (allValues != undefined && allValues.length > 0) {
                opts.push({
                    label: "--- None ---",
                    value: ""
                });
           }
            for (var i = 0; i < allValues.length; i++) {
                opts.push({

                    label: allValues[i],
                    value: allValues[i]
                });
            }
            component.find(elementId).set("v.options", opts);
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [lightning:select](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_select.htm) This is how we populate value

```
var opts = [
        { value: "Cyan", label: "Cyan" }, 
        { value: "Yellow", label: "Yellow" }, 
        { value: "Magenta", label: "Magenta", selected: true }];
    component.set('v.options', opts);
```

We don't have any class attribute here. Class attribute is present is ui:select. You need to change the code  and it will work as expected.

```
if (allValues != undefined && allValues.length > 0) {
    opts.push({
        label: "--- None ---",
        value: ""
    });
}
for (var i = 0; i < allValues.length; i++) {
    opts.push({
        label: allValues[i],
        value: allValues[i]
    });
}
component.find(elementId).set("v.options", opts);
```

Comment: Okay .In lightning select class attribute is present

Comment: @AnnappaPH yes in lightning:select class attribute is present. But I am asking to remove it from the option list and not from the parent attribute. You need to remove class from opts.

Comment: ya,got it thanks.. iam trying to make field "required" .In "ui" select  its little complex and in lightning:select i can easily do ..thanks Thushar..

Comment: hi Tushar,itsnt working.I have updated my question.

Comment: @AnnappaPH Share UI screenshot of what is not working.

Comment: values arenot coming in the picklist..

Comment: @AnnappaPH I'm hoping you are commenting the UI when using lightning. Also share how you are calling `fetchPickListVal`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74743/discussion-between-annappa-ph-and-tushar-sharma).